# Slider doesn't work, jquery.min.js included

Tags: jquery, html, slider

I am doing a slider in jquery, but unfortunately its not sliding. I included jquery.min.js and runing on DOM ready.

**slider.js**

```
$(function(){
    $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){
      $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut()
         .next('img').fadeIn()
         .end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 
      3000);
});
```

**html**

```
<script src="js/slider.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<div class="fadein">
     <img src="images/mtcRechargeSlider.jpg">
     <img src="images/iphoneSlider.jpg">
     <img src="images/accessoriesSlider.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try switch the js reference order.
Usually references like slider.js would depend on jquery. So just put jquery in front of slider.js, see how it works.

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/slider.js"></script>
```

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Plus, you can also inspect element in Chrome, see if there is any indicative messages from the console.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the jquery slider, you need include both jquery and jquery.ui files.
Here are the ones I typically include including a theme ...

```
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

            <script type=" text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"> </script>
            <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"> </script>
```

Comment: what i mean is the slider i provided in slider.js

Answer (score 0):

there sample looks more like this....

```
 <script>
   $(function() {
      $('#fadein).slidesjs({
        width: 940,
        height: 528,
        play: {
          active: true,
          auto: true,
          interval: 4000,
          swap: true,
          pauseOnHover: true,
          restartDelay: 2500
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
```